# "HitHighlightedSummary" property is not returning the searched keywords with <c0> tag, else it returns only plain text in PNP modern Search v4

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I am using PNP modern search V4 webparts in SharePoint online site. where i have linked search box and search results webpart. i need to highlight the Searched keyword in search results, i referred some documents where it stats "HitHighlightedSummary" will return the summery with highlighting the matched keywords, but in my case its simply returning the summery without highlighting the keywords. i am not sure what i am missing.

i have tried adding "HitHighlightedSummary" in Hit-Highlighted properties to but result is still same.

please find the below image for reference, where i have searched with word GCS but in "HitHighlightedSummary" it still returns plain summary.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kKpl.png)

Comment: It sounds like a PnP Modern Search specific/config issue. You might find the answer or somebody that can assist in resolving the issue at https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/discussions